# How to put addChildEventListener on multiple child dynamically in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add multiple listener on child added dynamically.

A-1,2,3 as child having messages.
B-2,3 as child having messages.
C-1,2 as child having messages.
D-1 as child having messages.

So want to monitor A, B and D for 1 message when they get added and others if they get added with 1.

Please help me i am stuck with this issue.

```
status.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                DataProvider chat= dataSnapshot.getValue(DataProvider.class);

                if(!chat.getStatus().isEmpty()) {
                    textView.setText(chat.getStatus());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {    
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {    
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {    
            }
```

This is the code which helps me to find out A,B,C but i am not able to monitor its children and grand children individually.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code of things you've tried? It's not quite clear what you're trying to do here and what you've already tried that hasn't worked.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald i have updated my question please have a look at it i want to monitor only the fields having 1 as user id in it and that to the parents may increase dyanmically to monitor on.